# What is the meaning of たくない ？

Tags: grammar, adjectives, suffixes, conjunctions

`食べない` is `I don't eat`, `食べたくない` is `I don't want to eat`.
So, `たくない` is `don't want to` where `たく` is the 連用形/Conjunctive of `たい` (the desire) + `ない`?
Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you have understood it correctly. There is nothing really complicated enough to justify a separate question here IMO.

Comment: This is kind of related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44013/43676